# Get and change function definition IDAPython

Tags: idapython

I was wondering if it is possible to retrieve the function definition at `ea` and eventually how to edit it. This feature should be in `idaapi` but unfortunately there's basically no documentation about that.

Comment: You mean to get the current function at n address? or get the function signature including parameters and return value?

Comment: The function signature including parameters and return value.

Comment: I don't think it's possible from ida python because of that part is done by hex-rays. It's not always 100% accurate anyway